# Source model "giftvoucher/templateoptions" not found for attribute "gift_template_ids"

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, module

**Source model "giftvoucher/templateoptions" not found for attribute "gift_template_ids"**
error occurs in the search result page.

I found similar questions like my question. But i did not get the result.

I don't know where the error come from. I have checked all modules.

Somebody advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope  `gift_template_ids` is `select or  drop down attribute`.

Guess you have creating `this attribute using installer`.As you have `creating dropdown and  multi selection` .. you need add source  `model for this attribute which is save it option and label`.
I hope `giftvoucher/templateoptions`” means(youmodulde_Model_Template) d`id not define option and labels.So this error occurs`

Comment: Ok. I will check

Comment: hi ..is it working or not???